# Anything I can do about someone looking through my responses and downvoting?

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

A few minutes ago I see this:

[image]

It's seemingly a single user going through my posts to downvote.  It's not a huge deal I guess, it's only a few rep - but it's (seemingly) someone being malicious.  I've never actually had to contact a moderator before, so am unclear on the process.

Comment: The user responsible has been warned, and these votes should be invalidated by the system within a day or so.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks much

Comment: that said a quick review of your questions show a large percentage of them are low quality and/or duplicates in one way or another deserving of down votes, just keep that in mind

Comment: @JarrodRoberson that may very well be, but the quality of the question shouldn't impact whether or not an answer is or isn't useful should it? Just trying to help out where I can, when I can ^^

Comment: but it does impact a persons opinion on whether it deserves a down vote or not, people have the freedom to distribute down votes how they wish for **no reason at all**, the fact that there are valid reasons should give you pause.

Comment: There does appear to be a growing number of people that down vote answers on question that should be/are closed as they feel they should not have been answered.  Not sure if that was the case here but it happens.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - All of the posts that were downvoted here had previously been upvoted, and looked to be good to me. I think you're being a little harsh on someone who clearly was targeted by indiscriminate downvotes. In fact, the trigger for this appears to be them explaining why they downvoted a low-quality question, so they were penalized for trying to maintain quality of the site themselves.

Comment: if you think that was harsh, even a little bit, your scale is set to overly sensitive.

Comment: @BradLarson heh... if it's the question I think you're referring too, I don't think I'm even the one that downvoted it.  But I guess you have more info than I do